# How can i get a NSDate from this string, and this NSDate to long or NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string date "Mar+5,+2014+4:00:00+AM"and I tried convert NSDate, and next get long(NSTimeInterval):

```
expireDate = @"Mar+5,+2014+4:00:00+AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM+dd,+yyyy+h:mm:ss+a"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:expireDate];

NSLog(@"%f", [dte timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

But, show me result: 0000.0. What the problem? Please help me. I need this date in long for store in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be necessary to set a locale, to be independent of
the user's settings:

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: @Zaph: You are right: *"All non-letter characters represent themselves in a pattern, except for the single quote."* - Perhaps the POSIX locale helps...

Comment: without the locale, the date formatter uses the system's and if that isn't en_XY then the date formatter won't parse march because that word isn't valid in any language but english

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code works, possibly change the format to %.0f to only show seconds.
Added an additional `NSLog` of the date for debugging.

```
NSString *expireDate = @"Mar+5,+2014+4:00:00+AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM+dd,+yyyy+h:mm:ss+a"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:expireDate];
NSLog(@"%@", dte);
NSLog(@"%.0f", [dte timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

NSLog output for my timezone (EST):

> 2014-03-05 09:00:00 +0000
>   1394010000

Comment: martin got it right I think. you need to set a locale or the date formatter won't scan march right in e.g. germany where it isn't mar ;)